# Powerpoint VBA - remove border/line/outline from shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I thought it would be an easy task: remove the line/border from a selected shape via VBA.

(`set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)`)

First try: `shp.line.weight = 0` --> there is still a very thin line around the shape. Interesting: same behaviour via GUI: if I set the line weight to 0 there a very thin line is still visible.

Second try: `shp.line.visible = false` --> line disappears but in the GUI none of the three options "no line", "single colored line", "gradient line" is selected. Deselecting and selecting the shape again let's "single colored line" flicker but in the end no option is selected. Weird ...

Is this a (known) bug?
Is there another VBA-option to disable the line?

What I tried else:
I checked `line.style` and `line.dashstyle` of a shape where I set "no line" via the GUI. Both values are -2. But it is not possible to set these values via VBA (error no valid value)

(Office 365)

Comment: >> "Second try: shp.line.visible = false --> line disappears but in the GUI none of the three options "no line", "single colored line", "gradient line" is selected."  Given that the line's supposed to be (and now is) invisible, is that a problem?  As to the flicker, a guess:  PPT retains whatever style was set before you made the line invisible and/or allows you to set different line formatting, but doesn't show it until you make the line visible.  Refreshing the formatting pane with the current line formatting, then disabling anything that's not relevant if the line's not visible maybe?

Comment: But it's irritating for the user ... moreover setting shp.fill.visible = false results in "no filling" being selected. That's why I think it's really a bug.

Comment: If the fill isn't visible, the shape has no fill, so why should this be a bug?  As to "irritating to the user", have you established that this happens on other/all computers or is it local to this user and users with similar computers?  It might be a video drive glitch, for example.

Comment: Yes - same result on other systems. Regarding shp.fill.visible: this works like expected. That's why I think shp.line.visible should work the same way - but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I also think that this is a bug.

Comment: No - unfortunately not :-/ . I definitely think it is a VBA bug.

Comment: Although the question is related to Offie 365 -> `shp.Line.Visible = false` is working in Office 2016. So most likely a bug it is. :'-(

Answer (score 2):

Try `shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse`, it worked for me.

You can find other LineFormat properties here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.lineformat

Comment: So the line is removed - but the formatting editor doesn't mark "no line" - see this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/G1EbWAs.png. Neither of the three options is selected - and that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the shape first. Then write one of your codes above

Comment: Shape is selected - code is explicitly working on selected shapes.