# VBA Powerpoint - VBA does not show borders

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a function that allows me to insert a specific number of rows below a specific row in my powerpoint table. Please note that this is no standard table - it has a format in which there is one "Content Row". After, there are 2 small (height) white rows before a next "Content Row" follows. The white rows are merely for optics and have a border in between.

The code is working well, however the very last operation at the bottom - to display the border in between the rows - does not work. Simply no border appears.

Thank you SO much for any input you can provide! <3

```
Private Sub Insert_Click()
'Read Input from UserForm
Answer1 = UserForm1.Answer1.Text
Answer2 = UserForm1.Answer2.Text
Unload UserForm1
'Analyze Row prior operation
SmallHeight = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows(2).Height
For repeat = 1 To Answer2

'Add Row
    'Paster after row
    BelowRow = 1 + 3 * (Answer1 - 1)

For i = 1 To 5
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows.Add (BelowRow)
    i = i + 1
Next

'Format "BelowRow" with Font and Text
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Cell(BelowRow, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange

    .Text = "Insert Caption"
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Size = "12"
    
End With

'Format two rows below "BelowRow"

intTableCols = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Columns.Count

For r = 1 To 3
BelowRow = BelowRow + 1

    For c = 1 To intTableCols
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Cell(BelowRow, c).Shape
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Fill.Transparency = 1
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = "1"
            .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0
            .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
            .TextFrame.MarginRight = 0
            .TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
        End With
    Next
    
    'Reduce Row Height
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows(BelowRow).Height = SmallHeight
    
    r = r + 1

Next

BelowRow = BelowRow - 1

'Add Border and Format
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows(6).Cells.Borders.Item(ppBorderTop)
.Weight = 3
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(77, 77, 77)
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a similar issue - lines not showing up for shapes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69272751/16578424 ... I really think my problem is a VBA but - maybe yours is similar

Comment: Why not use cell margins instead of extra rows for visual spacing? Then your problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, guys.

Unfortunately the solutions did not yet work for me. 

Anybody else with suggestions? Thanks!